# Multiple Youtube Players embedding issue using Youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I need multiple youtube player inside each `.player` div, But here only one player is loading with my code.
So can anyone please help me to find where is the problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var iframeCount = $('.player');
iframeCount.each(function (index) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'player-'+index);
});

var player, pId, playerText; 
$('.start-video').on('click', function (index) {     
    onPlayerStateChange = function (event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        event.target.destroy();
        }
    }   
    playerText = $(this).siblings('.player').text();
    pId = $(this).siblings('.player').attr('id');        
    
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    
    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
        player = new YT.Player(pId, {
           height: '244',
           width: '434',
           videoId: playerText,  // youtube video id
           playerVars: {
              'autoplay': 1,
              'rel': 0,
              'showinfo': 0
           },
           events: {
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
           }
        });
    }
    $(this).parent().find('.start-video').fadeOut();
});   
});
```

```css
.y-video{
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      min-width: 434px;
      min-height: 262px;      
  }
  .y-video img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 434px;
    height: 244px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }  
  .play-icon{
        display: inline-block;        
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        top: 42%;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 40px;
        font-size: 26px;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 4px 0 4px 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="y-video">
    <div class="player">gpzuVt_mkKs</div>    
    <span class="play-icon start-video">&#9655;</span>
    <img class="start-video" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/gpzuVt_mkKs/0.jpg">
  </div>
  
  <div class="y-video">
    <div class="player">Ep6U7vGjFw0</div>    
    <span class="play-icon start-video">&#9655;</span>
    <img class="start-video" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Ep6U7vGjFw0/0.jpg">
  </div>
  
  <div class="y-video">
    <div class="player">6lt2JfJdGSY</div>
    <span class="play-icon start-video">&#9655;</span>
    <img class="start-video" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/6lt2JfJdGSY/0.jpg">
  </div>
```

Comment: You are aware the you are creating multiple script tags due to appending them within your `.each()` loop `$('.y-video').each(function (index) `. Also, why not just have one player to play the videos? You could set the position of the video depending on which `img` is clicked...

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks !!! Now edited my code to remove each function and now loading the player on image click, but still it's load only one video who clicked first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used following reference to fix my issue: [http://jsfiddle.net/KtbYR/5/][1]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var iframeCount = $('iframe');
    iframeCount.each(function (index) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'player-'+index);
    });
});
    
function getFrameID(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if (elem) {
        if (/^iframe$/i.test(elem.tagName)) return id; //Frame, OK
        // else: Look for frame
        var elems = elem.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        if (!elems.length) return null; //No iframe found, FAILURE
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            if (/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com(\/|$)/i.test(elems[i].src)) break;
        }
        elem = elems[i]; //The only, or the best iFrame
        if (elem.id) return elem.id; //Existing ID, return it
        // else: Create a new ID
        do { //Keep postfixing `-frame` until the ID is unique
            id += "-frame";
        } while (document.getElementById(id));
        elem.id = id;
        return id;
    }
    // If no element, return null.
    return null;
}

// Define YT_ready function.
var YT_ready = (function() {
    var onReady_funcs = [],
        api_isReady = false;
    /* @param func function     Function to execute on ready
     * @param func Boolean      If true, all qeued functions are executed
     * @param b_before Boolean  If true, the func will added to the first
     position in the queue*/
    return function(func, b_before) {
        if (func === true) {
            api_isReady = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < onReady_funcs.length; i++) {
                // Removes the first func from the array, and execute func
                onReady_funcs.shift()();
            }
        }
        else if (typeof func == "function") {
            if (api_isReady) func();
            else onReady_funcs[b_before ? "unshift" : "push"](func);
        }
    }
})();
// This function will be called when the API is fully loaded

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    YT_ready(true)
}

var players = {};
//Define a player storage object, to enable later function calls,
//  without having to create a new class instance again.
YT_ready(function() {
    $(".thumb + iframe[id]").each(function() {
        var identifier = this.id;
        var frameID = getFrameID(identifier);
        if (frameID) { //If the frame exists
            players[frameID] = new YT.Player(frameID, {
                events: {
                    "onReady": createYTEvent(frameID, identifier)
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

// Returns a function to enable multiple events
function createYTEvent(frameID, identifier) {
    return function (event) {
        var player = players[frameID]; // player object
        var the_div = $('#'+identifier).parent();
        the_div.children('.thumb').click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.fadeOut().next().addClass('play');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $this.siblings('.thumb').hide();
            },150);
            if ($this.next().hasClass('play')) {
                player.playVideo();
                //player.destroy();
            }
        });
    }
}

// Load YouTube Frame API
(function(){ //Closure, to not leak to the scope
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api"; /* Load Player API*/
    var before = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    before.parentNode.insertBefore(s, before);
})();
```

```css
.y-video{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  clear: left;  
}
.play-icon{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 42%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 26px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    padding: 4px 0 4px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
img.thumb{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 281px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.y-video:hover .play-icon{   
      border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
      color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="y-video">
 <span class="thumb play-icon">&#9655;</span>
 <img class="thumb" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/gpzuVt_mkKs/0.jpg">
 <iframe width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gpzuVt_mkKs?enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&rel=0">
 </iframe>
</div>

<div class="y-video">
 <span class="thumb play-icon">&#9655;</span>
 <img class="thumb" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Ep6U7vGjFw0/0.jpg">
 <iframe width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ep6U7vGjFw0?enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&rel=0">
 </iframe>
</div>

<div class="y-video">
 <span class="thumb play-icon">&#9655;</span>
 <img class="thumb" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/6lt2JfJdGSY/0.jpg">
 <iframe width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6lt2JfJdGSY?enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&rel=0">
 </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the classes of each player (e.g. player1, player2 onwards), this will help your application separate each code/player.

Code snippet from a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17014882/5995040):

```
<div id="ytplayer1"></div>
<div id="ytplayer2"></div>

<script>
  var player;
  var player2;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer1', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'hdy78ehsjdi'
    });
    player2 = new YT.Player('ytplayer2', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '81hdjskilct'
    });
  }
</script>
```

There is also a Github code for [playing multiple videos using Youtube API iFrame](https://gist.github.com/thiagotargino/8564146).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but there will be n number of players on the each page, so I can't separate the classes of each player (e.g. player1, player2 onwards). Another side I will try Github code and let you know if it will work for me.